# When writing current url to csv TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list

Tags: python, list, csv, selenium, tuples

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list adding current url to new column

I'm running a script that gets current url and writing it to a csv file but I get:

```
    writer.writerow(row + (url1,))
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

because of this line: for row in data: in the below code (it works when not using driver.current url)

```
url1 = driver.current_url
with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row + (url1,))
```

If I add:

```
for row in zip(data):
```

This puts all the data in one column and link in column 2 where as I want each data in a different column.

I get:

```
   col1                          col2
['Clyde', 'Annan', '2.65', 'https://www.linkhere.com']
```

Desired:

```
col1    col2    col3     col4          
Clyde   Annan   2.65    https://www.linkhere.com
```

Any idea how I can get fix this?

Code:

```
import csv
import os
import time
from random import shuffle
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://www.betstar.com.au/sports/soccer/44317884-football-scotland-ladbrokes-league-2/')


# XPaths for the data
groups = "//*[@class='fullbox']"

xp_bp1 = ".//*[@class='row'][1]//td[1]"
xp_ba1 = ".//*[@class='row'][2]//td[1]"
xp_bp3 = ".//*[@class='row'][1]//span"

while True:
    try:
        # wait for the data to populate the tables
        #wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, (xp_bp1))))
        time.sleep(2)

        data = []
        for elem in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(groups):
            try:
                bp1 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_bp1).text
            except:
                bp1 = None

            try:
                ba1 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_ba1).text
            except:
                ba1 = None

            try:
                bp3 = elem.find_element_by_xpath(xp_bp3).text
            except:
                bp3 = None


            url1 = driver.current_url

            data.append([bp1, ba1, bp3, url1])
        print(data)
        url1 = driver.current_url
        with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in data:
                writer.writerow(row + (url1,))

    except TimeoutException as ex:
        pass
    except NoSuchElementException as ex:
        print(ex)
        break
```

Comment: Post the code in your question

Comment: Try `writer.writerow(row + [url1])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `data.append([bp1, ba1, bp3, url1])` which means when you do

```
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row + (url1,))
```

the `row` already contains the `url1`. You want the 4 data elements to appear in your csv, so change your code to:

```
for row in data:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 1):

`(url1,)` It creates a tuple and causing issue so a fix 
replace

```
with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row + (url1,))
```

with following code:

(also no need to do `+ (url1,)` as it is already getting appended to data `data.append([bp1, ba1, bp3, url1])`)

```
with open('test.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow("\t".join(row))
```

Comment: Is there a workaround so I can include current url and data like desired output?